# How Amazon ELB will distribute requests to Amazon EC2 instances of different instance types?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Anyone has any idea how the `ELB` will distribute requests if I register multiple `EC2` instances of different sizes. Say one `m1.medium`, one `m1.large` and one `m1.xlarge`.

Will it be different if I register `EC2` instances of same size? If so then how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a fairly complicated topic, mostly due to the [Amazon ELB](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) routing documentation falling short of being non existent, so one needs to assemble some pieces to draw a conclusion - see my answer to the related question [Can Elastic Load Balancers correctly distribute traffic to different size instances](https://serverfault.com/a/386527/10305) for a detailed analysis including all the references I'm aware of.

For the question at hand I think it boils down to the somewhat vague AWS team response from 2009 to [ELB Strategy](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=129199#129199):

> **ELB loosely keeps track of how many requests (or connections in the
>   case of TCP) are outstanding at each instance.**  It does not monitor
>   resource usage (such as CPU or memory) at each instance.  ELB
>   currently will round-robin amongst those instances that it believes
>   has the fewest outstanding requests. *[emphasis mine]*

Depending on your application architecture and request variety, larger [Amazon EC2 instance types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) might be able to serve requests faster, thus have less outstanding requests and receive more traffic accordingly, but either way the ELB *supposedly* distributes traffic appropriately on average, i.e. should implicitly account for the uneven instance characteristics to some extent - I haven't tried this myself though and would recommend both, [Monitoring Your Load Balancer Using CloudWatch](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_MonitoringLoadBalancerWithCW.html) as well as monitoring your individual EC2 instances and correlate the results in order to gain respective insight and confidence into such a setup eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I agree with Steffen Opel, also I met one of the solution architect of AWS recently, he gave couple of heads up on Elastic Load balancing to achieve better performance through ELB.

1) make sure you have equal number of instances running on all the availability zones. For example in case of ap-southeast, we have to availability zones 1a and 1b so make sure you have equal number of instances attached to the ELB from both the regions.

2) Make sure your application is stateless, that's the cloud enforces and suggests the developers.

3)Dont use sticky sessions.

5)Reduce the TTL (Time to live) to the maximum possible level, like 10 secs or something.

6) Unhealthy checks TTL should be minimum so that ELB doesn't retain the unhealthy instances.

7)If you are excepting a lot of traffic to your ELB make sure you do a load testing on ELB itself, it doesn't scale as fast as your ec2 instances.

8) If you are caching then think thousand times from which point you are picking the data to cache.

Above all tips is just to help you get this better. Its better you have a same size of instances.